Notify about Pending Messages in Microsoft Teams
How can I create a pop-up to tell me if I have unread messages in MS Teams?  I sometimes miss the brief MS Teams message banners for hours, even while working at the computer.  I don't know if it is a bug or if I am just too "in the zone"/looking at the wrong monitor.
I used to have a tool for this using Auto Hotkey (AHK) scripting.  The Teams icon in the system tray changed names when there was Teams activity, so I could periodically read through the icon names and pop up a message.  I'll include that code below.  But the "New Teams" circa 2023 quit updating the icon name in the system tray, so now my script never fires.
What else can I use in the New Teams to periodically interrupt me (only when someone wants my attention)?  I am considering a constant check for the banner.  But I don't know how to mask notifications about messages that I already read (that would be important to reduce annoyances).  I recognize that I can turn on the Team setting for "Missed activity emails" every 10 minutes.  But those don't do any better for catching my attention.
SetTimer, windows_to_front, 10* 60 * 1000  ; 10 minutes
    windows_to_front:
    DetectHiddenWindows On
    Check_for_Teams_Notification()

Check_for_Teams_Notification() {  ; from TrayIcon.ahk @ https://gist.github.com/tmplinshi/83c52a9dffe65c105803d026ca1a07da -- AHK ver 1
    ; Loop through all potential traytip msgs in the system tray:
    DetectHiddenWindows, On
    global Username
    For key, sTray in ["Shell_TrayWnd","NotifyIconOverflowWindow"] {
        idxTB := TrayIcon_GetTrayBar()
        WinGet, pidTaskbar, PID, ahk_class %sTray%
        hProc := DllCall("OpenProcess", UInt, 0x38, Int, 0, UInt, pidTaskbar)
        pRB   := DllCall("VirtualAllocEx", Ptr, hProc, Ptr, 0, UInt, 20, UInt, 0x1000, UInt, 0x4)
        SendMessage, 0x418, 0, 0, ToolbarWindow32%idxTB%, ahk_class %sTray%   ; TB_BUTTONCOUNT
        szBtn := VarSetCapacity(btn, (A_Is64bitOS ? 32 : 24))
        szNfo := VarSetCapacity(nfo, (A_Is64bitOS ? 32 : 24))
        szTip := VarSetCapacity(tip, 128 * 2)
        Loop, %ErrorLevel% {
            SendMessage, 0x417, A_Index - 1, pRB, ToolbarWindow32%idxTB%, ahk_class %sTray%   ; TB_GETBUTTON
            DllCall("ReadProcessMemory", Ptr, hProc, Ptr, pRB, Ptr, &btn, UInt, szBtn, UInt, 0)
            dwData   := NumGet(btn, (A_Is64bitOS ? 16 : 12))
            iString := NumGet(btn, (A_Is64bitOS ? 24 : 16))
            DllCall("ReadProcessMemory", Ptr, hProc, Ptr, dwData, Ptr, &nfo, UInt, szNfo, UInt, 0)
            DllCall("ReadProcessMemory", Ptr, hProc, Ptr, iString, Ptr, &tip, UInt, szTip, UInt, 0)
            trayt                              := StrGet(&tip, "UTF-16")
            ; msgbox %trayt%
            if (inStr(trayt, "Microsoft Teams")) 
            && (inStr(trayt, "New Activity")) {
                teams_msg_was_found := true
                ; msgbox "Found MS Teams & New Activity"
            } ; end if
        } ; end loop
    } ; end for
    if (teams_msg_was_found and !WinActive("ahk_exe Teams.exe"))
    {
        MsgBox 0x40001, APPL ALERT, "MS Teams has an alert", 60
    } ; end if
} ; end function


Microsoft Power Automate can be utilized to set up a workflow that periodically scans for unread messages in Teams. Upon detecting any unread messages, this workflow can initiate a notification on your desktop.
Ref Doc: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-automate/trigger-flow-teams-message

That was an interesting idea. I got as far as "When a new chat message is added" -> "Send me a mobile notification" before getting stuck, even though that is not really my desired solution.  It looks like someone else has my same unfulfilled wish: https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/General-Power-Automate/Get-an-email-when-a-teams-chat-goes-unread-for-X-amount-of/td-p/2020634

You can use WorkFlows to Notify about Pending Messages in Microsoft Teams.
Learn more about the Workflows app here.
To learn more about creating workflows in Teams, follow below documents:

Creating a workflow from a chat in Teams

Creating a workflow from a channel in Teams

Add or run a workflow from a message within Microsoft Teams


